# Install VCRedist 2010 through WSUS?

Tags: windows, deployment

I need to deploy VCRedist 2010 to our fleet of computers, as we are rolling out an application that relies on it. We already have WSUS and a self-publishing solution in place, so it *should* be relatively easy to deploy both the vcredist and the application at once.

Has anyone had experience installing the vcredist this way, and is it contrary to the licensing agreement?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I figured it out-- Run the vcredist_x86.exe, it unzips to C:\. Take the vc_red.msi and vc_red.cab and publish them using [Local Update Publisher](http://www.localupdatepublisher.com/) or similar...

Don't forget to set the architecture in the IsInstallable rule!